# Android ExifInterface Horizontal Flip Undefined

Tags: android, android-camera, exif

After taking a picture using the Google Vision Library ([CameraSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource)) I grab the orientation from Exif data using

```
int orientationValue = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

This is giving me the rotation of the camera at the time the image was taken however I can't get information on which camera was being used (front or back). There is a warning in the logs from the ExifInterface stating the following:

```
W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2
```

However ExifInterface defines 2 as `public static final int ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL = 2;`.

Why is this information not being parsed? Is there a different tag I need to use to get this information? The images are also not horizontally flipped when viewing in the gallery.